# Android Kotlin Coroutine UnitTesting

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've got a broadcastReceiver that starts a coroutine and I am trying to unit test that...

The broadcast:

```
class AlarmBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    Timber.d("Starting alarm from broadcast receiver")
    //inject(context) Don't worry about this, it's mocked out

    GlobalScope.launch {
        val alarm = getAlarm(intent)
        startTriggerActivity(alarm, context)
    }
}

private suspend fun getAlarm(intent: Intent?): Alarm {
    val alarmId = intent?.getIntExtra(AndroidAlarmService.ALARM_ID_KEY, -1)
    if (alarmId == null || alarmId < 0) {
        throw RuntimeException("Cannot start an alarm with an invalid ID.")
    }

    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        alarmRepository.getAlarmById(alarmId)
    }
}
```

And here's the test:

```
@Test
fun onReceive_ValidAlarm_StartsTriggerActivity() {
    val alarm = Alarm().apply { id = 100 }
    val intent: Intent = mock {
        on { getIntExtra(any(), any()) }.thenReturn(alarm.id)
    }

    whenever(alarmRepository.getAlarmById(alarm.id)).thenReturn(alarm)

    alarmBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(context, intent)

    verify(context).startActivity(any())
}
```

What's happening is that the function I'm verifying is never being called. The test ends before the coroutine returns... I'm aware that `GlobalScope` is bad to use, but I'm not sure how else to do it.

EDIT 1:
If I put a delay before the `verify`, it seems to work, as it allows time for the coroutine to finish and return, however, I don't want to have test relying on delay/sleep... I think the solution is to properly introduce a scope instead of using `GlobalScope` and control that in the test. Alas, I have no clue what is the convention for declaring coroutine scopes.

Comment: Have you tried using `runBlocking`? Coroutines are asynchronous!

Comment: I have yes. Still getting `Wanted but not invoked`. I think I need to properly handle the scope (instead of using globalScope) but alas I don't know what the proper way is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see, You will have to use an [`Unconfined`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-unconfined.html) dispatcher:

> `val Unconfined: CoroutineDispatcher (source)`
>
> A coroutine dispatcher that is not confined to any specific thread. It executes the initial continuation of a coroutine in the current call-frame and lets the coroutine resume in whatever thread that is used by the corresponding suspending function, without mandating any specific threading policy. Nested coroutines launched in this dispatcher form an event-loop to avoid stack overflows.
>
> Documentation sample:
>
> ```
> withContext(Dispatcher.Unconfined) {
>    println(1)
>    withContext(Dispatcher.Unconfined) { // Nested unconfined
>        println(2)
>    }
>    println(3)
> }
> println("Done")
> ```

For my ViewModel tests, I pass a coroutine context to the ViewModel constructor so that I can switch between `Unconfined` and other dispatchers e.g. `Dispatchers.Main` and `Dispatchers.IO`.

Coroutine context for tests:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class TestContextProvider : CoroutineContextProvider() {
    override val Main: CoroutineContext = Unconfined
    override val IO: CoroutineContext = Unconfined
}
```

Coroutine context for the actual ViewModel implementation:

```
open class CoroutineContextProvider {
    open val Main: CoroutineContext by lazy { Dispatchers.Main }
    open val IO: CoroutineContext by lazy { Dispatchers.IO }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
@OpenForTesting
class SampleViewModel @Inject constructor(
        val coroutineContextProvider: CoroutineContextProvider
) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {

    private val job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = job + coroutineContextProvider.Main
    override fun onCleared() = job.cancel()

    fun fetchData() {
        launch {
            val response = withContext(coroutineContextProvider.IO) {
                repository.fetchData()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

#### Update

As of coroutine-core version `1.2.1` you can use `runBlockingTest`:

Dependencies:

```
def coroutines_version = "1.2.1"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:$coroutines_version"
```

e.g:

```
@Test
fun `sendViewState() sends displayError`(): Unit = runBlockingTest {
    Dispatchers.setMain(Dispatchers.Unconfined)
    val apiResponse = ApiResponse.success(data)
    whenever(repository.fetchData()).thenReturn(apiResponse) 
    viewModel.viewState.observeForever(observer)
    viewModel.processData()
    verify(observer).onChanged(expectedViewStateSubmitError)
}
```

Comment: So basically, you'd inject your ContextProvider and use it as a threadPool. Fair play. Also, I tried doing the same - inject the dispatchers and use Unconfined in my tests and everything looks good! - Thanks!

Comment: I use `CoroutineScope` in my ViewModels so that I can control the lifecycle of the job and then use the CoroutineContext there whenever I make calls.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah as Rodrigo Queiroz mentioned, run blocking will solve the issue.

```
@Test
fun onReceive_ValidAlarm_StartsTriggerActivity() = runBlockingTest {
    val alarm = Alarm().apply { id = 100 }
    val intent: Intent = mock {
        on { getIntExtra(any(), any()) }.thenReturn(alarm.id)
    }

    whenever(alarmRepository.getAlarmById(alarm.id)).thenReturn(alarm)

    alarmBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(context, intent)

    verify(context).startActivity(any())
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. 
That will block the thread for any suspend functions called, however, the function is within a launch so it doesn't work... :(

Still getting: `Wanted but not invoked`. If I put a delay before the verify it works, but I don't want to do that!

Comment: it is deprecated